# Does drawing a new canvas delete the contents on the old canvas?

Tags: java, android, image, canvas, bitmap

see title

If I have a drawCircle on a canvas but continually make a new canvas by the code below, will the old Circle go away? I understand it may not be efficient but I am curious.

```
ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Background);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawCircle(point0,point1,10,paint);
background.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Thanks

Comment: No. But I guess you will soon fill out your memory and get an OOM exception.

Comment: How do I continually make I a new drawCircle then.. while deleting/erasing the old?

Comment: Do I have to use clearCircle at the beginning of a thread? Or do I erase repeatedly in a thread? Or do I set the color to transparent/clear repeatedly in a thread? How would you recommend going about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to create new a new Canvas everytime you which to change the background image.
Just use the already existing canvas and set the bitmap on it

```
// Have your variables like this
ImageView background;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;

// Associate them to the respective views
background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Background);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

// instead of creating a new canvas, just update the already existing with your bitmap
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
canvas.drawCircle(point0,point1,10,paint);
background.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

**Update** : *Thanks for the remark from @Doomsknight*
If you wish to clear the canvas, you can simply do :

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.White);
```

and it will erase all the drawn content

Comment: I do not wish to set the background image. I got that. I wish to update (and erase/delete the old) the drawCircle. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomHogan You can clear a canvas by using `canvas.drawColor(Color.White);`. if you are just trying to blank it all. Do not create a new canvas. If you want to remove Just the circle, then you could clear the canvas, and redraw everything back onto it. Or use a second bitmap to store the image without the circle, and just draw that back on.

Comment: `canvas.drawColor(Color.White);` will make the canvas **white**. Which may or not be what the OP wants.

Comment: So if I am in a thread that repeats every seconds if I have the canvas.drawColor(Color.White) at the beginning of the thread and canvas.drawCiircle at the end, it will work?